# LaTeX templates/packages for writing a patent specification

Tags: packages, templates

Are there any templates or useful packages for writing a patent specification, such as the ones in this [collection](http://www.freepatentsonline.com/)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know about these two. The first one looks good and was successful used by the author for his patent applications. The other one is quite old: it is packed as [shell archive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shar) and for LaTeX2.09, but works well with a modern LaTeX2e.
I can't tell you more about them. All my patent applications had to be written in MS Word.

http://dodge.stanford.edu/~echmelar/inventions.html (look for "`template.tar.gz`")

http://www.ibiblio.org/patents/txt/temptex.txt ([shell archive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shar))

Comment: The link suggested above: http://dodge.stanford.edu/~echmelar/inventions.html (look for "template.tar.gz") is down. Do you know of any other place to find this package?

Comment: @Sven: I converted your "answer" to a comment. We want to keep the answer space reserved for actual answers. If you would like to post it as follow-up question, please use the "Ask Question" link for your new question; there you can link to this question to provide the background.

Comment: @Sven: No, I don't. Just give it some time. It might only be a temporar issue.

Answer (score 12):

I recently uploaded a new [template for drafting U.S. patent applications](http://ctan.org/pkg/uspatent) to CTAN. It should be what you are looking for. Or, [Google "uspatent LaTeX LyX CTAN"](https://www.google.com/search?q=uspatent+LaTeX+LyX+CTAN) to find it.

Comment: It looks very nice! Thanks and congratulations for the work

Answer (score 2):

I found this LaTeX template online on this link:

- https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/other/us-patent

Answer (score 1):

## Starting from 2023: DOCX required

> Filing a new non provisional 111(a) application?  Starting January 1, 2023, specification, claims and abstracts not filed in DOCX format will incur a non-DOCX surcharge of up to $400 for this filing type.

See USPTO: [**File patent application documents in DOCX**](https://www.uspto.gov/patents/docx)

If you hate M$ Word as much as I do, writing the application in [Markdown](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html) using the [Vim text editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)) and converting it to [DOCX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) using [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org) and the provided USPTO DOCX template, might be a very viable option.