# The output of alternative LaTeX compilers (detex, pandoc) appears to be much worse than pdflatex, what could be the causes?

Tags: macros, pdftex, pandoc, detex

I'm compiling a LaTex document that uses the following US Patent style:

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-uspto-patent-and-response-letters/qtzkqddwxjbj

Which relies heavily on macros. By default, pdflatex is used and it yield correct result.

When the same document is compiled by pandoc or detex, most references created my macro are missing. The following code gives a typical example:

latex code:

```
\documentclass[english]{uspatent}

...

\annotationDefinition{workingSurfaces}
\annotationName{working surfaces}

\annotationDefinition{concentricStruts}
\annotationName{concentric struts}

...

\patentParagraph In \referencePatentFigure{Fig3}, both links are mounted in a concentric position: namely, the \annotateWithName{workingSurfaces} fold forward if both \annotateWithName{concentricStruts} contract
```

pdflatex output:

```
[027]
In FIG. 3, both links are mounted in a concentric position: namely, the
working surfaces [ 6 ] fold forward if both concentric struts [ 12 ] contract
```

pandoc output:

```
In , both links are mounted in a concentric position: namely, the  fold forward if both  contract
```

detex output:

```
In Fig3, both links are mounted in a concentric position: namely, the workingSurfaces fold forward if both concentricStruts contract
```

So pandoc performs the worst by completely ignoring all the macro definitions in the documentclass. detex is slightly better, but it converts \annotationDefinition directly into text, despite that it is just a reference binding.

I wonder if there are ways to improve pandoc or detex to ensure consistency with pdflatex (e.g. by reading the intermediate output of the later). What argument and compilation chain should I use for this? Or are they already abandoned by the community?

Comment: What is your ultimate goal?  Why are you trying pandoc or detex in the first place?

Comment: Are you suggesting that pandoc & detex are abandonwares? I'm just converting latex to pure text for Google/DeepL machine translation

Comment: `detex` hasn't changed in a couple years, but I'm not sure it's been abandoned. `pandoc` is definitely still actively developed. But I don't think either of them are really meant for doing what you're trying to do, particularly with a nonstandard document class. They aren't "compilers" at all., but source converters. Some other workflows to try: `make4ht` + `pandoc` (on the resulting html), `tex4ebook` + `ebook-convert` (from calibre) on the resulting epub, `pdflatex` + `pdftotext` (poppler) or `ps2ascii` (ghostscript) (or `ebook-convert`) on the resulting pdf.

Comment: Pandoc is not to "compile" anything,  but to **export** from a format (like latex) to another format (like plain text?) . The pandoc opuput depend a lot of the power of the the target format. E.g.:, if you export a latex with figures to plain text, of course the output will not have any figure. Detex is just to strip commands, and although it can interpret some commands as `\input` and echo the argument of some cross references (with -c), the retain that the whole idea is just remove commands (macros) to clean the raw plain text.

Comment: USPTO: _"Filing a new non provisional 111(a) application?  Starting January 1, 2023, specification, claims and abstracts not filed in DOCX format will incur a non-DOCX surcharge of up to $400 for this filing type."_ See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/665668/26348

Comment: @SergeStroobandt gee this is outrageous, I'll pay someone $200 to get a working DOCX  compiler just to creep USPTO out :-)